# Convert cURL command to ansible

Tags: curl, ansible, devops

I have two cURL commands which I'm trying to convert to Ansible.  They look like this:

```
curl -v -ik --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "X-Application-Username: my_username" --header "X-Application-Password: my_password" --request PUT --data '{"enabled":"False","persisted" : true,"concurrentExecution" : false, "type" : "cron","schedule" : "0/10 * * * * ?","invokeService" : "provisioner","invokeContext" : { "action" : "someAction","source" : "path/to/resource"}}' "https://localhost:8443/path/to/url/that/I/need"


curl -v -ik --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "X-Application-Username: my_username" --header "X-Application-Password: my_password" --request PUT --data '{"enabled":"True","persisted" : true,"concurrentExecution" : false, "type" : "cron","schedule" : "0/10 * * * * ?","invokeService" : "provisioner","invokeContext" : { "action" : "someAction","source" : "path/to/resource"}}' "https://localhost:8443/path/to/url/that/I/need"
```

I've tried to convert to ansible, but it isn't working.  What I've come up with so far is this:

```
- name: Run cURL commands
  hosts: role_app_server[1]
  vars:
    endpoint: "https://localhost:8443/path/to/url/that/I/need"
    cron_schedule: "0/10 * * * * ?"
    invocation_context:
      action: "someAction"
      source: "path/to/resource"
  tasks:
    - name: First task
      uri:
        url: "{{ endpoint }}"
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          X-Application-Username: "my_username"
          X-Application-Password: "my_password"
        method: PUT
        body:
          enabled: "False"
          persisted: "true"
          concurrentExecution: "false"
          type: "cron"
          schedule: "{{ cron_schedule }}"
          invokeService: "provisioner"
          invokeContext: "{{ invocation_context | to_json }}"
        body_format: json
        validate_certs: no
    - name: 2nd task
      uri:
        url: "{{ endpoint }}"
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          X-Application-Username: "my_username"
          X-Application-Password: "my_password"
        method: PUT
        body:
          enabled: "True"
          persisted: "true"
          concurrentExecution: "false"
          type: "cron"
          schedule: "{{ cron_schedule }}"
          invokeService: "provisioner"
          invokeContext: "{{ invocation_context | to_json }}"
        validate_certs: no
        body_format: json
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In what way is the playbook not working?

Comment: It runs in ansible but the endpoint is not being called correctly, with the result that it's not running the command correctly on the server.

Comment: Use https://curlconverter.com/ansible/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can diagnose this problem using a debugging endpoint like https://httpbin.org, which you can use to see exactly what data your requests are sending.

Using the following playbook, we make the request first with `curl` and then with the `uri` module, in each case storing the respond from `httpbin` so that we can compare them:

```
---
- name: Run cURL commands
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    endpoint: "https://httpbin.org/put"
    cron_schedule: "0/10 * * * * ?"
    invocation_context:
      action: "someAction"
      source: "path/to/resource"
  tasks:

    - name: First task (curl)
      command: >-
        curl -k -o output-curl1.json 
        --header "Content-Type: application/json"
        --header "X-Application-Username: my_username"
        --header "X-Application-Password: my_password"
        --request PUT
        --data '{"enabled":"False","persisted" : true,"concurrentExecution" : false, "type" : "cron","schedule" : "0/10 * * * * ?","invokeService" : "provisioner","invokeContext" : { "action" : "someAction","source" : "path/to/resource"}}'
        "{{ endpoint }}"

    - name: First task (uri)
      uri:
        url: "{{ endpoint }}"
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          X-Application-Username: "my_username"
          X-Application-Password: "my_password"
        method: PUT
        body:
          enabled: "False"
          persisted: "true"
          concurrentExecution: "false"
          type: "cron"
          schedule: "{{ cron_schedule }}"
          invokeService: "provisioner"
          invokeContext: "{{ invocation_context | to_json }}"
        body_format: json
        validate_certs: no
        return_content: true
      register: output1

    - copy:
        content: "{{ output1.content }}"
        dest: ./output-task1.json
```

You can just manually inspect the results, but it's probably easier if we combine `jq` and `diff` to highlight the differences:

```
$ diff -u <(jq -Sr .data output-curl1.json | jq -S .) <(jq -Sr .data output-task1.json | jq -S .)
--- /dev/fd/63  2019-04-07 18:00:46.597729568 -0400
+++ /dev/fd/62  2019-04-07 18:00:46.599729606 -0400
@@ -1,12 +1,9 @@
 {
-  "concurrentExecution": false,
+  "concurrentExecution": "false",
   "enabled": "False",
-  "invokeContext": {
-    "action": "someAction",
-    "source": "path/to/resource"
-  },
+  "invokeContext": "{\"action\": \"someAction\", \"source\": \"path/to/resource\"}",
   "invokeService": "provisioner",
-  "persisted": true,
+  "persisted": "true",
   "schedule": "0/10 * * * * ?",
   "type": "cron"
 }
```

This highlights a few differences. The biggest one appears to be the content of the `invokeContext` attribute.  When using `curl`, the value of that attribute is a JSON object:

```
$ jq -r .data output-curl1.json | jq .invokeContext
{
  "action": "someAction",
  "source": "path/to/resource"
}
```

But when using the `uri` module, the value of `invokeContext` is a string:

```
$ jq -r .data output-task1.json | jq .invokeContext
"{\"action\": \"someAction\", \"source\": \"path/to/resource\"}"
```

This is happening because you're passing the value of your `invocation_context` variable through the `to_json` filter:

```
invokeContext: "{{ invocation_context | to_json }}"
```

That means when the `body` data structure in your task is serialized into JSON, the `invokeContext` -- which you have *already* converted into a JSON string -- gets double-converted.  You want this:

```
invokeContext: "{{ invocation_context }}"
```

You also have some boolean vs. string conflicts.

When using `curl` you're setting the `persisted` attribute to boolean `true`, but in your Ansible task you're setting it to the string value `"true"`.  Instead of:

```
persisted: "true"
```

You want:

```
persisted: true
```

And lastly, you have the same issue with the `concurrentExecution` attribute, which should be:

```
concurrentExecution: false
```

With all these changes, the first task becomes:

```
- name: First task (uri)
  uri:
    url: "{{ endpoint }}"
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      X-Application-Username: "my_username"
      X-Application-Password: "my_password"
    method: PUT
    body:
      enabled: "False"
      persisted: true
      concurrentExecution: false
      type: "cron"
      schedule: "{{ cron_schedule }}"
      invokeService: "provisioner"
      invokeContext: "{{ invocation_context }}"
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: true
  register: output1
```

And if we repeat our earlier `diff` command, we see that the data send by `curl` and by the `uri` module is identical:

```
$ diff -u <(jq -Sr .data output-curl1.json | jq -S .) <(jq -Sr .data output-task1.json | jq -S .)
$ # no output from the previous command
```

Comment: thanks so much.  It's still not quite working.  Could it be something to do with the -v -ik flags?  I'm not certain what they do.